# Stop a playback in Freeswitch

Tags: audio, lua, playback, freeswitch

I have some code in Lua that answers a call, and after performing a series of operations bridges the call to a new leg.

The operations take from a few seconds to several minutes.

To keep the client I need to play a sound the issue I have is that the playback is still going on after the call is bridged.

The specific question is, how to stop a sound called from a playback ?

My code looks like

```
session:answer()
session:execute("playback", '/some/file.wav')
.
.
.
local connectionString = '{bypass_media=true,origination_caller_id_number=555,destination_number=646}'
connectionString = connectionString .. 'sofia/external/192.168.0.1@1000'
session:execute('bridge', connectionString)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar task, and solved it by launching a new script for the outbound leg. When the outbound leg is answered, I send `uuid_break` to the inbound leg, and let the channels bridge together. It's done in Perl, but Lua should be quite similar:  https://github.com/xlab1/freeswitch_secretary_bug   (the scripts are in scripts directory).

From [the `mod_commands` documentation](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_commands):

> #### `uuid_break`
>
> Break out of media being sent to a channel. For example, if an audio
>   file is being played to a channel, issuing `uuid_break` will
>   discontinue the media and the call will move on in the dialplan,
>   script, or whatever is controlling the call.
>
> **Usage**: `uuid_break <uuid> [all]`
>
> If the `all` flag is used then all audio files/prompts/etc. that are
>   queued up to be played to the channel will be stopped and removed from
>   the queue, otherwise only the currently playing media will be stopped.

But in general, it's much easier to implement such scenarios via ESL: your program can handle multiple channels via ESL asynchronously, and perform all the needed playbacks and breaks easily. Here I made a simple prototype in Golang to implement a similar scenario via ESL:  https://github.com/xlab1/go-fs-secretary-prototype (here I used the synchronous outbound ESL socket, but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement it also in asynchronous inbound mode).

I hope this helps :)

Comment: indeed that's the right direction, thanks for the answer

Comment: Also here examples and scripts, I forgot to give this link https://github.com/voxserv

Comment: For perl its $session->execute( 'break' );